# ¿Como mandar parametro a un metodo de C# mediante una llamada ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Lo que quisiera lograr es poder pasar un parametro desde mi funcion de javascript a travez de ajax pero que dicha variable le llege a mi metodo de c# que estoy llamando.

Codigo ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../../pagina/configuracion/empresa/confEmpresa.aspx/getPlanta",
        data: { var1: 0},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de esta manera pero cuando cargo la pagina no me sale informacion, antes me salia la informacion corretamente, pero hize esta modificacion y ya dejo de funcionar. ¿Estoy realizando el envio de la variable de forma incorrecta?

No me ha salido ningun error en consola y al parecer la carga de la pagina se rompe ya que no muestra informacion, el servidor no recibe el parametro y por ende no se ejecuta el metodo. si la peticion es exitosa me deberia mostrar un accordeon con todas las plantas de mi empresa dependiendo de la BD.

Codigo C#

```
 #region getPlanta
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getPlanta(int identificador)
    {
        string resultado = "";

            List<DataTable> listado = new List<DataTable>();
            Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
            resultado = empresa.getPlanta();
            string conteo = resultado.Substring(resultado.Length - 1);



            /**listado=getAutorizaciones(conteo);**/


        return resultado;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: ¿Algún error en consola? ¿El servidor recibe algo? ¿Qué hace si la petición es exitosa? Podrías añadir esos y más detalles para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Así como planteas tu pregunta no hay mucho qué decirte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../../pagina/configuracion/empresa/confEmpresa.aspx/getPlanta",
        data: { var1: 0},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

**C#**

```
public static string getPlanta(int identificador)
```

OJO! Porque `var1 != identificador` nunca se enviarán los datos, siempre identificador en el lado del servidor será **null**, para solucionar esto, ambos nombres de variables deben ser iguales. Reemplaza var1 por identificador.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es tu función en JQuery:

function getDatos() {
    if (validaCampos()) {

```
    var oParam = "{ 'FechaIni': '" + $('#fechaIni').val() + "','FechaFin': '" + $('#fechaFin').val() + "' }";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Graficas.aspx/GetInformacion",
        data: oParam,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var datos = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

        },
        error: function (msg) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Y así lo invocas desde .NET:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetInformacion(string FechaIni, string FechaFin)
{
    PedidosBLL pBll = new PedidosBLL();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pBll.GetInformacion(FechaIni, FechaFin));
}
```